# How to test a springboot controller that is calling an external REST API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Basket Microservice that is calling into an external Payment REST API to make payment during checkout.

How do I test my BasketController that is going to call into an external REST service to make payment? Is there a way to mock this rest service?

Any reference link or similar code samples is appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier to answer this question if you could provide us a minimal example of the code you're trying to test. From your description it's not clear to me whether the controller and the API-call you make are within the same class, or within separate classes and whether you're using `WebClient`, `RestTemplate`, .... The reason I'm asking is because some of these have dedicated testmodules, while others don't. For now, I'm voting to close this question because answering all these possibilities is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Best would be either to intercept the call (eg by mocking your rest client eg RestTemplate and method verify the call) or mock whole external API with a tool like Wiremock and verify actual HTTP request that has been made.